# Identifyng the date format

Tags: java, date, locale

Consuming a webs service, which is returning date in a format that is not able to identify.

```
              <Date>1140711</Date>
              <Time>94255</Time>
```

Its in Century +yy+MM+dd format, if the date is 20140711 (yyyyMMdd) then it will be 1140711. So how can I convert these date like 1140711to 07/11/2014(MM/dd/yyyy)

Comment: 1140711? What do you expect this date to be read as? 11/40/711? 11/07411? 1/14/0711?

Comment: @bot:This is the response getting from the web service. Not sure how to interpret this.It is said to be in MM/dd/yyyy. It is US locale but in different format.

Comment: Use another web service. It is under documented, buggy or both.

Comment: Is there at least an idea which day and time this "date" should represent?

Comment: @laune,@Henry,@bot :This is in Century +yy+MM+dd, so this will be 2014/07/11. How can I convert this into MM/dd/yyyy in java

Comment: What datatype is the date after you extract it from the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the only way this might make sense is as 114-07-11, as if a programmer had forgotten to add 1900 to the return value of year taken from a Date.

So: July 11, 2014.

Chances are, that this programmer also didn't add 1 to the month, so it might just as well mean

Or: August 11, 2014.

The time might be 09:42:55

**Later** To convert the date by decomposing and adding 1900:

```
String cmd = "1141126";
int len = cmd.length();
int day = Integer.parseInt( cmd.substring( len - 2 ) ); 
int month = Integer.parseInt( cmd.substring( len - 4, len - 2 ) ); 
int year = 1900 + Integer.parseInt( cmd.substring( 0, len - 4 ) ); 
String mdc = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
```

Comment: Its Century +yy+MM+dd
 format, if the date is 20141126 (yyyyMMdd)  then it will be 1141126 . So how can I convert these date like 1141126  to 11/26/2014(MM/dd/yyyy)

Comment: @user630209 A few lines of code, from string to string.